# Collision not working

Tags: game-engine

Help me please I need to pass this work tomorrow

What's wrong with my work? I want that if the character collides with the obs or walls the game would restart but somehow it's not working.
Here is the file : http://www.pasteall.org/blend/37842

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the only way the player collides with the walls is because go that small white box. You could either get rid of the box and just use the character, or stretch the box upwards so it collides with the walls on top too, although this may be unnecessary.

To make the restarting game properly work, you the game property called 'obs' should be set to boolean and 'True'. Also, delete the sensor for the collision with the property of 'prop'.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Should I really delete the sensor with 'props'? I some of the walls obs and I got lazy so I just press add game property to the rest. And thank you for the response :) I'll try if it will work.

Comment: Yeah, I deleted that 'prop' sensor and then changed the obs to boolean true and it worked fine! :)

Comment: Another way round it, without having to delete the sensor with 'props' would be to replace the 'and' controller for an 'or' controller. This is because what it was doing with your blend file is restarting the game if it was colliding with the 'obs' property AND 'prop' property, which isn't what you wanted